# Lucene 5.4 - scoring divided by number of search terms?

Tags: solr, lucene, text-mining, scoring

I have a simple setup with IndexSearcher, QueryParser, SimpleAnalyzer.
Running some queries I recognised that a query with more than one term returns a different ScoreDoc[i].score than shown in explain query statement. Apparently it is the score shown in explain divided by the number of search terms. any explanation for this behaviour?

```
Running search(TERM1 TERM2 TERM3)
line:term1 line:term2 line:term3
2.167882 = sum of:
  0.6812867 = weight(line:term1 in 6594) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
    0.6812867 = score(doc=6594,freq=2.0), product of:
      0.5389907 = queryWeigh

totalHits 1
1678413725, TERM1 TERM2 TERM3, score: 0.72262734
```

I understand the coord() statement would be used to penalise documents which include only a subset of the search terms provided. However this document includes all terms. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: seems like the division does only occur if the query is configured to use OR statements instead of AND. So using OR queries and matching all terms is still divided by the number of terms in the search query. I couldn't find this part in the documentation but at least it explains the difference.

However applying QueryWrapperFilter seems to change the scoring again. Although according to the documentation it should only filter the results without impact on scoring.

---

More details

These two scores are result of the same query. Only the second query gets divided

```
0.114700586 = product of:
  0.34410176 = sum of:
    0.34410176 = weight(line:term1 in 24) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
      0.34410176 = score(doc=24,freq=1.0), product of:
        0.5389907 = queryWeight, product of:
          8.17176 = idf(docFreq=14, maxDocs=19532)
          0.065957725 = queryNorm
        0.63841873 = fieldWeight in 24, product of:
          1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
            1.0 = termFreq=1.0
          8.17176 = idf(docFreq=14, maxDocs=19532)
          0.078125 = fieldNorm(doc=24)
  0.33333334 = coord(1/3)

item_id: 1495958818, item_name: term 1 dolor sit met, score: 0.114700586


0.18352094 = product of:
  0.5505628 = sum of:
    0.5505628 = weight(line:term 1 in 6112) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
      0.5505628 = score(doc=6112,freq=1.0), product of:
        0.5389907 = queryWeight, product of:
          8.17176 = idf(docFreq=14, maxDocs=19532)
          0.065957725 = queryNorm
        1.02147 = fieldWeight in 6112, product of:
          1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
            1.0 = termFreq=1.0
          8.17176 = idf(docFreq=14, maxDocs=19532)
          0.125 = fieldNorm(doc=6112)
  0.33333334 = coord(1/3)

item_id: 1677761523, item_name: some text term 1, score: 0.061173648
```

Comment: How are you producing the item_id: .. debug values? How does the response directly from the server look in the admin console?

Comment: The index is stored as StringField and and the content is stored as TextField. Using Luke I get the same result. Which debug values would be required?